# App is crashing when loading custom xib file for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When I try to load custom UITableViewCell app crashes. I've done this many times before and this time I did it the same way. Part of the code where which cause crash is commented (// This part is causing crash):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";

    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

       // This part is causing crash
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    }

     return cell;

}
```

There is CustomTableCell.h, CustomTableCell.m and CustomTableCell.xib.

CellIdentifier is CustomTableCell and there is no space problem with nib name.

Screenshot of error:
[image]

What could be a reason for crash?

Comment: Please add the crash message or error which you are getting while the app is crashed.

Comment: set your identifier in the CustomTableCell.xib

Comment: @Manohar - CellIdentifier is ok.

Comment: @RajanBalana - addedd screenshot of error

Comment: this causes memory leak. you are allocating bundle everytime without freeing it

Comment: can you put the console crash?

Comment: @ForamMukundShah: The provided code shouldn't cause memory leaks, because the Nibs loaded from a bundle are views provided by iOS (which handle the memory).

Comment: yes, it will not cause memory leak, instead we can say it will cause extra burden to the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I created new xib file for custom cell and everything is ok now.

Comment: Thank you! I spent ~2hours on this damn bug in <xcode?>.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Custom Cell's connection instead of File's Owner in class. ?
[image]

Comment: everything is ok with that

Comment: ok. I thought it may be an issue with xib because it happens many time. Anyways Happy Coding.

Comment: @MS. why not files owner. When Im loading xib in a view it should coonect to filesowner naa

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
#import "customCell.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Configure the cell.
   static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"customCell";
   customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil)
   {
      NSArray *nib;
      nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];

      for (id oneObject in nib)
          if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[customCell class]])
             cell = (customCell *)oneObject;

      cell.lbl.text = @"Hello";
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Hopefully, it'll help you.

Comment: Normally, `nib` has an element,so i think there is no difference between your code and his code. If there is,please explain it to me.

Comment: @mstfbsnli :: In my code, I've added for loop for all objects in custom cells. So it'll automatically reference for cell

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomTableCell *cell;
   cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableCell"];

   NSArray *nib;
   for (UIControl *subview in cell.contentView.subviews) {
      [subview removeFromSuperview];
   }

   if(cell == nil)
   {
       nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

       for(id oneobject in nib)
       {
          if([oneobject isKindOfClass:[CustomTableCell class]])
          {
             cell = (CustomTableCell *)oneobject;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok so far. What could be the problem is, that you didn't link the xib to your customized class in the editor. And if so, you might have a problem, that some of the linked Outlets don't exist (or so, it depends on the errors).

You can link your customized table view cell in the editor under "Custom Class". Do so by clicking in the xib file editor on your custom cell (in the left section you find the Section "Objects" and below this, you should find your table view cell).
If you have the Attribute-Editor open, click on the thrid tab (so you see, where you can set your custom class. Enter the name of your class (in your case, its "CustomTableCell"). Click the right arrow right next to the entered class to verify, if your custom class exists. Recompile (optional make a clean) and it should work fine.

Comment: Please provide us some of the error logs. This might really help us track down the error much quicklier. You could also delete company specific or somehow related parts.

Comment: I guess you have a typo in your code. I know, this sounds obviouse but do the classes "CustomTableCell" (not just the files, because you've shown us, that they exist) exist? Like: <<NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" (i guess, the class-name you load isn't right) owner:nil options:nil];>> When you insert a breakpoint at this line, does it load any nibs?